# Code for a PWA to respond to a 200

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I want to test my Progressive web application for offline status. I want that if my webapp if offline, it should respond with a 200 status code. What can be the possible code for that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the section about How to ask a question here https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and especially 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

This is not a code writing service for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not detailed enough to give a detailed answer but in general:

it sounds like the 200 status code is from an HTTP request, in which case if your PWA uses javascript (e.g. via ajax) to make the remote API calls (e.g. GET) then you just handle the state in the returned event object, e.g. you have to handle other states (e.g. other types of failures too). For example see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

You also could also test the online/offline state before making the HTTP request.

See [discussion](https://justmarkup.com/log/2016/08/indicating-offline/) of using `navigator.onLine` or adding

```
window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) {//do something}, false);
window.addEventListener('online', function(e) {//do something}, false);
```

Another example is I use Polymer webcomponents and firebase authentication for my PWAs and in [Polymerfire](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/firebase/polymerfire/elements/firebase-auth) it's simply a case of handling the `online` property.